# pcm512x module problem, blacklisting it doesn't help

Tags: archlinux, modules

I keep having the following message during boot, reboot and I see in dmesg log.

```
pcm512x 1-004c: Failed to reset device: -5
```

I'm on the ArchLinux ARM. I've been googling, found [this](http://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=7066), unfortunately blacklisting the module `snd_soc_pcm512x` doesn't help.

I suppose this module is related to sound, I don't need sound on my Pi, so I would rather prefer to disable it completely then recompile the module manually.

Any ideas?